# How can i display unknown format media?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media

I have a non-extension URL that refer to a file like image, audio or video.
I want to display these media properly but I don't know which HTML element should be used. I know there are image element, `<video>` and `<audio>` element but I need one element that cover all of these because I can't detect format of file from URL.

How can I solve this problem by front end technology?
Are there any HTML element or plugin that can display medias dynamically based on format?

Comment: perhaps an `<object>`, does your server send this unknown file with a useful mime type?

Comment: no, server does not send useful mime type

Comment: Have you tried object tag anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use iframe here as a container to get any link to access without any problem.

I am not sure about your links still below is an example that how it works

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OhFel6HTHu8">
</iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9i4/e7e/9i4e7ebkT.jpeg">
</iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1asouch1/

Comment: Your youtube example is irrelevant since this doesn't point to a video media file.

Comment: What about your other links ? Is they supports into your browser using iframe ? I just want to know if iframe is an option that helps you to achieve your task. Thanks for upvote :)

Comment: Hum I'm not the asker. Just pointing out that your youtube example is not a good one. Normally modern browsers will support video audio and images in `<iframe>` just like in `<object>` or `<embed>`

Comment: oh, okey. iframe cannot support watch url of youtube, so have to embed it.

Comment: No my point was that your url does point to an html document, not a video file.

Comment: it seems iframe can not load image in your example. i can see video file but image file can not be load in iframe.